# Marcar (colorir) uma string para escrever no arquivo

Tags: java, string, arquivo

Minha aplicação procura por algumas palavras em um arquivo.
Quando o programa reconhecer essas palavras (strings), ele deve marca-la.
Por exemplo: mudar a cor da fonte ou mudar a cor de fundo da palavra.

Então irei escrever o mesmo texto, porém com a cor de fonte da palavra diferente. Irei escrever em pdf ou em doc, o que for mais fácil para fazer isso.

Não sei nenhuma função que faça isso e nem se quando for escrever o arquivo conseguirei escrever com esse detalhe.

Continuei a procurar e encontrei `class StyleContext` mas não tenho ideia de como ela funciona.

Comment: O Java não possui suporte nativo nem para o formato DOC nem para PDF, você deve procurar conhecer uma biblioteca para resolver seu problema. Exemplo: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) para DOC e [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) para PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o seu texto de entrada é bastante simples (suponho que seja pelo fato de querer *colorir uma `String`*). Acredito que a opção mais fácil e que ainda poderá inclusive abrir no word sem problemas é usar RTF (*Rich Text Format*).

Embora exista o [suporte nativo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) [ao RTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html), o suporte é bastante limitado. Porém a [especificação do mesmo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10725) é extremamente simples e poderá implementá-la por conta.

Tudo o que precisará é definir as cores desejadas:

```
\\cores    \\ \cf1 = Preto #000000 \cf2 Vermelho #FF0000  \cf3 = Azul #3200FF 
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red50\\green0\\blue255;}\n
```

Abaixo um exemplo que faz exatamente o que disse:

 <sub>[Baixe no gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/9f94f01e8d4760ff3db3)</sub>

RTF.java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class RTF {
    private StringBuilder texto;
    public String getTexto() {
        return texto.toString();
    }
    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = criaRTF(texto);
    }
    public StringBuilder criaRTF(String text){
        StringBuilder arquivortf = new StringBuilder("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0\n");
                                    // \cf1 = Preto (cor padrao)      ;\cf2 = vermelho        ;\cf3 =  Azul
        arquivortf.append("{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red50\\green0\\blue255;}\n");
        arquivortf.append(text);
        arquivortf.append("\n}");
        return arquivortf;
    }
    public void colorirTexto(String palavra)
    {
        //Colore com a cor Azul i.e \cf3
        String palavraColorida = "{\\cf3" + palavra + "}";
        int indice = texto.indexOf(palavra);
        while (indice != -1)
        {
            texto.replace(indice, indice + palavra.length(), palavraColorida);
            // vai ao fim da substituicao
            indice += palavraColorida.length();
            indice = texto.indexOf(palavra, indice);
        }
    }
    public void salvaRTF(String nomeArquivo){
        try {
            PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(nomeArquivo + ".rtf");
            saida.println(texto);
            saida.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

TestaRTF.java

```
public class TestaRTF {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\n" +
                        " Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum\n"     +
                        " sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,\n" + 
                        "nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,\n"   + 
                        "pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa\n"  + 
                        " quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,";
        RTF rtf = new RTF();
        rtf.setTexto(texto);
        rtf.colorirTexto("quis");
        rtf.salvaRTF("arquivoColorido");
    }
}
```

Caso a sua entrada for textos mais complexos (i.e não é texto puro) sugiro que assim como o  [Anthony disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29355/marcar-colorir-uma-string-para-escrever-no-arquivo#comment54689_29355) que use bibliotecas para DOC ou para PDF.

Comment: Então.. minha aplicação têm um string bem grande (é um texto dentro da string) e vou percorrendo palavra por palavra.. e quando encontrar certas ocorrências, marcarei (colorir) essa palavra...
Dae, no final eu terei um string igual a da entrada, com a diferença que algumas palavras estarão "marcadas". E ai sim eu irei colocar a string em um arquivo PDF ou DOC.

Comment: Minha entrada é PDF, mas ja tratei ela.. entao o conteúdo fica em uma string. Acho que isso facilita.